# Why code below a loop is executing while loop is not over yet?

Tags: javascript, synchronous

I am trying to generate random n(value of n to be provided manually) primes so that I can see the lag in browser, as this is a long synchronous process. But when I am running the code below I am getting the output ("Finished generating the prime number") which is followed by a while loop instantly even the while loop had not finished its work.
The way I am figuring that while loop is not finished is by looking in the console.

```
const number = document.querySelector(".number"); // "number" class is in HTML on `<input>` element
function isPrime(n) {
  let prime = true;

  for (let i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return n > 1;
}

function generatePrimes() {
  message.innerText = "generating prime number....";
  let count = 0;
  while (count != number.value) { // number.value is the value provided in input element by user.
    let number = random(10000);
    if (isPrime(number)) {
      console.log("Hi"); // to check that while loop not finished yet
      count++;
    }
  }
 // this is the line getting executed instantly.
  message.innerText = "Finished generating prime number";
}
```

even the "Hii" count in console increases in with time, the last line of the generatePrimes() function is getting executed as soon as I am invoking it.
What I am expecting is that the last line of generatePrime() function should run once the while loop done its work utill that point broweser should be unresponsive to do any other task.

Comment: What exactly is the output, what exactly would you expect and why would you expect that?? It is perfectly possible the loop stops after the second iteration if number was randomly chosen to be a prime in the first iteration and 1 in the second iteration.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. It references `number.value` without definition of `number`.

Comment: I had explained the question in more detail now.

Comment: What is `random`? Please make sure we can reproduce the problem you speak of. You could edit your question and insert a runnable snippet using the toolbar button (providing HTML, CSS and JavaScript).

Comment: How have you determined that the while loop has not finished its work? What is the proof of that? Which number have you entered in the input element that gives the surprising result?

Comment: Because it actually finished the loop and the console output is just slow and didn't catch up yet. Also for some reason outputting the same string makes it slower. Try again by making the output unique.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few aspects that may give you the wrong impression that the loop is still going on when the final output is being made:

- JavaScript is not slow. It can perform a hundred thousand loop iterations in a "split of a second".
- The `console` interface is asynchronous. It may display the result of a `console.log` somewhat later than when it was executed... This is all up to the host (browser) that runs the JavaScript code. Certainly when you have tens of thousands of calls of `console.log`, the console will not show those thousands of lines instantly and may still be outputing when the JavaScript code has already run to completion. Again, this is all in the hands of the browser.
- The first output "generating prime number...." will not be visible on the web page until there is a repaint cycle. But that paint cycle can only happen when your code has run to completion. Until then the user interface is blocked. So that means the first and last output to the `message` element happen together and you'll never see the first message. To resolve that, delay the processing code a bit after you have output the initial message. You can do this with `setTimeout`, which will execute the loop and the last output as part of an asynchronous job, allowing at least one paint cycle to occur before that executes.

Here is a runnable snippet that does not output every single time to the console during the loop, as this is just not helpful when you expect tens of thousands of outputs.

```js
const number = document.querySelector(".number");
const message = document.querySelector(".message"); 
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", generatePrimes); 

function random(end) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * end);
}

function isPrime(n) {
  for (let i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return n > 1;
}

function generatePrimes() {
  message.innerText = "generating prime number....";
  setTimeout(function () {
    let count = 0;
    while (count != number.value) {
      let number = random(10000);
      if (isPrime(number)) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    message.innerText = "Finished generating " + count + " prime numbers.";
  });
}
```

```html
Number: <input class="number" type="number" value="1000000"><button>Go</button><br>
Message: <span class="message"></span><br>
```